# Heraussuchen, suchen oder finden

Tags: meaning-in-context

Welches Wort wäre in der folgenden Situation am besten:

Ein Kunde kennt seine Kundennummer nicht; anhand der anderen Information möchte ich den Kunden **im System** finden.

> Ich muss also die Kundennummer heraussuchen/suchen?

Soll ich sagen:

> Ich muss Ihre Kundennummer heraussuchen/finden?

Und wäre es richtig:

> Ich werde für Sie die Daten im Internet/im System heraussuchen?

Comment: Wir werden, ich werde. Mehrzahl/Einzahl. Ich habe die Sätze umgestellt, weil die Hervorhebung vollständige Sätze nahelegt, in denen das Oder nicht funktioniert.

Comment: "Ich muss Ihre Kundennummer anhand anderer Informationen *herausfinden*." wäre auch noch eine Alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### suchen

Suchen bedeutet, sich zu bemühen, an etwas zu gelangen, das verloren wurde oder versteckt ist. Das Wort deckt mit seiner Bedeutung nur das Bemühen ab, nicht aber den Erfolg. Das Wort *suchen* enthält keine Information über die Art des Ortes an dem gesucht wird. (Man etwas *auf, in, unter, hinter* usw. suchen.)

---

### heraussuchen

Wie *suchen*, jedoch mit dem Unterschied, dass nun auch angegeben wird, dass die Suche *in* etwas (z.B. in einem Behälter) stattfindet, und dass die Absicht besteht, im Fall des Erfolges das Gefundene aus diesem Etwas herauszunehmen.

---

### finden

*Finden* ist der Erfolg einer Suche. Von *finden* spricht man aber auch, wenn man durch Zufall an eine Sache gelangt, ohne dass daran andere Personen beteiligt sind. (Wer durch eine Fußgängerzone geht, und plötzlich einen Flyer in der Hand hat, hat ihn meist nicht *gefunden,* sondern *bekommen,* obwohl es sich auch dabei um ein eher zufälliges Ereignis handelt.)

---

In Bezug auf die Frage bedeutet das:

**suchen**

Diese Sätze sind auf jeden Fall richtig:

> Ich muss die Kundennummer suchen.
> Ich werde für Sie die Daten im Internet suchen.
> Ich werde für Sie die Daten im System suchen.

<sup>Beachte, dass all das keine Fragen sondern Aussagen sind! Bei geschlossenen Fragen (man erwartet als Antwort *ja* oder *nein*) steht das Verb an Position 1: *»Muss ich die Kundennummer suchen?« »Werde ich für Sie die Daten im Internet suchen?«* Bei offenen Fragen (man erwartet etwas anders als *ja/nein* als Antwort) steht davor noch ein Fragewort: *»Wann muss ich die Kundennummer suchen?« »Warum werde ich für Sie die Daten im Internet suchen?«*</sup>

*Suchen* drückt das Bemühen aus, und genau dieses Bemühen verlang der Kunde in diesen Sätzen von dir. Die Präpositionalobjekte *»im Internet«* und *»im System«* (beachte: *im = in dem*) enthalten neben der Lokalpräposition *in* auch beide ein Dativobjekt (*dem Internet* bzw. *dem System*), und *»in«* plus Dativobjekt ergibt eine Ortsangabe. Damit lieferst die also die Angabe, *wo* die Suche stattfindet, und das ist in diesen Beispielen auch ganz in Ordnung so.

**heraussuchen**

Das ist richtig:

> Ich muss die Kundennummer heraussuchen.

Damit gibst du an, dass von dir verlangt wird, dich zu bemühen, an die Kundennummer zu gelangen, wobei sich die Kundennummer innerhalb etwas befindet, und du die Absicht hast, sie im Erfolgsfall aus diesem Etwas herauszuholen.

Das ist aber falsch:

> Ich werde für Sie die Daten **im** *<sub>(= **in dem**)</sub>* System heraussuchen.

Der Teil *heraus* drückt eine Bewegung aus, die von einem Ort ausgehet, der mit *innen* bezeichnet werden kann, und an einem Ort endet, der als *außen* bezeichnet werden kann, wobei sich der Sprecher *außen* befindet:

> Hans kommt aus dem Haus heraus.

Das bedeutet: Der Sprecher steht außerhalb des Hauses, Hans war vorher im Haus, und bewegt sich gerade von innen nach außen. Auch hier liegt ein Präpositionalobjekt, bestehend aus Lokalpräposition und Dativobjekt vor, aber die Lokalpräposition ist hier: *»aus«*.

Das wäre nämlich falsch:

> Hans kommt **in** dem Haus heraus.

Wir brauchen keinen festen Ort (*in* + Dativobjekt), sondern den Ausgangspunkt einer Bewegung (*aus* + Dativobjekt).

Und daher muss es richtigerweise heißen:

> Ich werde für Sie die Daten **aus dem** System heraussuchen.

**finden**

> Ich muss ihre Kundennummer finden.

Das setzt dich unter den Zwang, bei der Suche erfolgreich zu sein. Der Kunde kann das zwar verlangen, aber wenn seine Kundennummer nicht im System ist, wirst du zwar die Sache mit dem Bemühen (also das Suchen) hinbekommen, aber beim Finden wirst du scheitern. Grammatikalisch ist der Satz also in Ordnung, aber es wird hier etwas verlangt, das vielleicht nicht geleistet werden kann.

Nachdem im Wort *finden* keine Bewegung steckt, findet das Finden auch an einem festen Ort statt, und erfordert daher die Präposition *in*:

- richtig

  > Ich muss ihre Kundennummer **im** *<sub>(= **in dem**)</sub>* System finden.
- falsch

  > Ich muss ihre Kundennummer **aus dem** System finden.

Answer (score 2):

Sofern es sich um ein Telefonat handelt, würde ich etwas wie das empfehlen:

> Sie haben Ihre Kundennummer nicht parat? Dann muss ich Ihren Datensatz
>   anhand Ihrer Anschrift heraussuchen.

Anstelle von *»heraussuchen«* wäre auch *»suchen«* möglich, auch *»finden«*, Letzteres dürfte aber das Ungebräuchlichste sein.

Comment: ... oder, da es sich beim Telefonieren ja um mündliche Sprachverwendung handelt, meistens einfach. "Dann muss ich Ihren Datensatz anhand Ihrer Anschrift **raussuchen**". Man würde, wenn man leger unterwegs ist, allerdings auch kaum das doch eher schriftsprachliche "anhand" benützen sondern eher das einfachere, wenn auch im Schriftsprachlichen nicht ganz angemessene "über": "Dann muss ich Ihren Datensatz über Ihre Anschrift raussuchen". Wobei "über" hier kurz für "auf dem Wege über" steht.